# MySQL INNER JOIN multiple rows same value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join

Both of the following tables have 2 entries for the same player.

Table punishment :
[image: table punishment]
Table cooldown :
[image: table cooldown]

```
SELECT punishment_id, punishment.reason, cooldown.id, cooldown.time_left FROM player INNER JOIN punishment ON player.most_uuid=punishment.most_uuid INNER JOIN cooldown ON player.most_uuid=cooldown.most_uuid WHERE player.most_uuid=2941535451391147758
```

In the result of this query I have some kind of "duplicated" rows.
I get 4 rows when I'd like to have just 2 with the essentials values inside.

Result from the query[image: result of the query]

I need all the values present in the rows, but as you can see there are pairs of rows with the exact same value twice.

Is there a possibility of merging them to actually have 2 like this (and not having duplicated values):

[image]

Comment: I can't read your images at all.  That is why text tables (or perhaps sample data on a fiddle site) are so helpful.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I edited it to be as comprehensible as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think :

```
SELECT punishment_id, punishment.reason, cooldown.id, cooldown.time_left FROM player INNER JOIN punishment ON player.most_uuid=punishment.most_uuid INNER JOIN cooldown ON player.most_uuid=cooldown.most_uuid WHERE player.most_uuid=294153545139114775
```

Can be transform in :

```
SELECT punishment_id, punishment.reason, cooldown.id, cooldown.time_left FROM punishment INNER JOIN cooldown ON punishment.most_uuid=cooldown.most_uuid WHERE punishment.most_uuid=294153545139114775
```

This only work if you don't want to check existence on player table.

If you did it on purpose, I recommend using GROUP BY :

```
SELECT punishment_id, punishment.reason, cooldown.id, cooldown.time_left FROM player INNER JOIN punishment ON player.most_uuid=punishment.most_uuid INNER JOIN cooldown ON player.most_uuid=cooldown.most_uuid WHERE player.most_uuid=294153545139114775 GROUP BY punishment_id
```

I hope this is usefull. Bye